# Minimum number of points to specify a sine wave with a given accuracy

Tags: continuous-signals

I am generating a sine wave from a DAC at a constant frequency. If each full cycle is specified by N data points what is the relationship between the accuracy of the rendered sine wave and N?

N=1 will obviously be pulses. N=4 (peaks and zero crossings) will yield a triangular wave of sorts. Is there some equation that shows how good a sine wave approximation is being created? [Obviously I can put it through a post DAC filter to smooth it etc]

The kind of answer I am looking for is: "Specifying a sine wave with N points yields 1:X accuracy"

Comment: A bit more info. I am interested in this as part of a range finding experiment using ultrasonics. I want to compare the entirety of the reflected wave with the transmitted one, not just a single peak to peak one off measurement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are asking is "what is the sample rate required to sample a sine wave for a given precision". This is basically what the sampling theorem is all about (See for example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem). The surprising answer is (more or less): "more than two". Once you meet the sampling criteria you are fine and 
the accuracy does NOT increase by sampling more often.

In your case, 3 points per period will work fine (provided your DAC has a proper anti-aliasing filter).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a formula, but I do know from experimentation that N=256 gives a sine wave with a reasonable SNR for general audio use, although if you want full 16 bit accuracy (i.e. > 90 dB SNR) you'll probably need to go higher than this.

If you're stepping through the sine wave LUT at a non-integer rate (to generate an arbitrary frequency) then using interpolation between LUT values reduces SNR such that you can use a smaller LUT than if you don't interpolate (e.g. if you just truncate the sample index).